# Change Mouse Hover Popup Color

Tags: gui

[image]

Is there some way to change the background of the popup, that is shown when you hover on some element in the GUI, like the string '507 bytes' in this picture, to white and the string to black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact solution depends on what exactly is managing your desktop and the theme you're using.

Try editing `/path/to/your/theme/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` after making a backup. Look for something like:

```
gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#ffffff\nfg_color:#4c4c4c\ntooltip_fg_color:#ffffff\nselected_bg_color:#f07746\nselected_fg_color:#FFFFFF\ntext_color:#3C3C3C\nbg_color:#F2F1F0\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000\nlink_color:#DD4814"
```

and modify `tooltip_bg_color` or `tooltip_fg_color` to alter the background and text colors, respectively.

So, you'd have `#ffffff` for  `tooltip_bg_color` and `#000000`for `tooltip_fg_color`.

Then, log out and log in again to make sure the changes take effect. If you're using some sort of tool that let's you change themes, change away and back.

If that doesn't help, look at `/path/to/your/theme/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` or at `/path/to/your/theme/gtk-3.0/gtk-main.css` for similar code right near the top of the file. Make appropriate edits and log out and in or switch themes.

---

With specific reference to the [Moka](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=160565) theme, assuming it's installed in `/usr/share/themes/Moka`, edit `/usr/share/themes/Moka/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and change:

```
# Moka GTK2 Theme

gtk_color_scheme = "bg_color:#f7f7f7\nselected_bg_color:#a172d2\nbase_color:#fefefe" # Background: main, selected, base 
gtk_color_scheme = "fg_color:#444\nselected_fg_color:#f3f3f3\ntext_color:#444"       # Foreground: main, selected, text
gtk_color_scheme = "tooltip_bg_color:#444\ntooltip_fg_color:#FFF"                    # Tooltips
gtk_color_scheme = "link_color:#a172d2"                                              # Hyperlinks
gtk_color_scheme = "menubar_bg_color:#f7f7f7\nmenubar_fg_color:#444444"              # Menu bar colors
gtk_color_scheme = "toolbar_bg_color:#f7f7f7\ntoolbar_fg_color:#444444"              # Toolbar colors
gtk_color_scheme = "menu_bg_color:#ffffff\nmenu_fg_color:#444444"                    # Menu colors
gtk_color_scheme = "panel_bg_color:#444444\npanel_fg_color:#f7f7f7"                  # Panel colors
```

to

## Moka GTK2 Theme

```
gtk_color_scheme = "bg_color:#f7f7f7\nselected_bg_color:#a172d2\nbase_color:#fefefe" 
gtk_color_scheme = "fg_color:#444\nselected_fg_color:#f3f3f3\ntext_color:#444"       
gtk_color_scheme = "tooltip_bg_color:#fff\ntooltip_fg_color:#000"             #### Change this line 
gtk_color_scheme = "link_color:#a172d2"                                              
gtk_color_scheme = "menubar_bg_color:#f7f7f7\nmenubar_fg_color:#444444"              
gtk_color_scheme = "toolbar_bg_color:#f7f7f7\ntoolbar_fg_color:#444444"              
gtk_color_scheme = "menu_bg_color:#ffffff\nmenu_fg_color:#444444"                    
gtk_color_scheme = "panel_bg_color:#444444\npanel_fg_color:#f7f7f7"
```

Then, in `/usr/share/themes/Moka/gtk-3.0/gtk-common.css` look for the section titled **tooltips** which starts on ~ line 217 and change the first two lines so that that section looks like this:

```
/* Tooltips */
@define-color tooltip_bg_color @bg_color;
@define-color tooltip_fg_color @text_color;
@define-color theme_tooltip_bg_color @tooltip_bg_color;
@define-color theme_tooltip_fg_color @tooltip_fg_color;
```

Then, log out and back in.

You haven't mentioned where you've installed this theme, but if it is in /usr/share/themes/Moka, you'll need to use **gksudo** if you're editing with a GUI-based editor such as Gedit.

If you've installed the theme in ~/.themes, then **gksudo** isn't needed.

Comment: I am using the [Moka](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=160565) theme. I tried to do as you said, but nothing really happened. Could you please download the theme and tell me which part I should change?

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks a lot! Just one more thing.. After changing the colors, there's a shadow effect on the tooltip text. Can it be removed?

Comment: I suggest you **ask a separate question** and include information about your OS and its version, the exact desktop environment (Unity? GNOME? XFCE? LXDE?), the file manager, and what  manages your desktop? Also include an image just of the tooltip area and a little of the surrounding to show what you mean.